# UIButton Subclass - Overriding getters to return placeholder/default values

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm in the process of converting a custom `UIButton` from Objective-C to Swift which has custom properties and default values for those properties:

MyButton.h

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *buttonColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *buttonSelectedColor;

// ...

@end
```

MyButton.m

```
@implementation MyButton

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {    
        [self adjustButtonColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self adjustButtonColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    [super setSelected:selected];

    [self adjustButtonColor];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    [self adjustButtonColor];
}

- (void)adjustButtonColor
{
    if (self.selected || self.highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [self buttonSelectedColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [self buttonColor];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Default colors

- (UIColor *)buttonColor
{
    if (!_buttonColor) {
        _buttonColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    return _buttonColor;
}

- (UIColor *)buttonSelectedColor
{
    if (!_buttonSelectedColor) {
        _buttonSelectedColor = [self.buttonColor colorWithAlphaComponent:.5];
    }
    return _buttonSelectedColor;
}

#pragma mark - Public

- (void)setButtonColor:(UIColor *)buttonColor
{
    _buttonColor = buttonColor;

    [self updateButton];
}

@end
```

I have attempted to replicate this pattern in Swift with public vars which return a default value, or access a private optional variable which is returned if it exists.  I have also overridden the `selected` and `highlighted` properties, updating the button colors in `didSet`:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    private var _buttonColor: UIColor?
    var buttonColor: UIColor {
        get {
            if let color = _buttonColor { return color }
            return UIColor.grayColor()
        } set {
            _buttonColor = newValue
        }
    }

    private var _buttonSelectedColor: UIColor?
    var buttonSelectedColor: UIColor {
        get {
            if let selectedColor = _buttonSelectedColor { return selectedColor }
            return self.buttonColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
        } set {
            _buttonSelectedColor = newValue
        }
    }

    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            adjustButtonColor()
        }
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            adjustButtonColor()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        adjustButtonColor()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        adjustButtonColor()
    }


    func adjustButtonColor() {
        if selected || highlighted {
            backgroundColor = buttonSelectedColor
        } else {
            backgroundColor = buttonColor
        }
    }
}
```

A few questions:

1. Is this an appropriate use of private variables?  Is there any way to accomplish the behavior I want with a single variable rather a second optional settable variable for each color?
2. Is overriding `UIButton` properties to call `adjustButtonColor` in `didSet` abuse of the getter/setter?
3. If `initWithCoder` is a failable initializer do I need to check if `self` is `nil` before calling `adjustButtonColor()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this an appropriate use of private variables? Is there any way to accomplish the behavior I want with a single variable rather a second optional settable variable for each color?

This can be much easier accomplished with a *lazy* stored property:

```
lazy var buttonColor: UIColor = UIColor.grayColor()
lazy var buttonSelectedColor: UIColor =  self.buttonColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

The right-hand side is evaluated exactly once, when the property
is accessed the first time. This makes the private `_xxx` variables
obsolete. (I think that you seldom need such a "shadow copy" in Swift.)

But there seems to be no real need for `buttonColor` to be evaluated
lazily. If you make it an ordinary stored property then you can add
a property observer:

```
var buttonColor = UIColor.grayColor() {
    didSet {
        self.updateButton()
    }
}
```

If you want `buttonSelectedColor` to be computed from `buttonColor` then 
it needs to be a lazy property, otherwise you could make it a stored
property as well:

```
var buttonSelectedColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

> Is overriding UIButton properties to call adjustButtonColor in didSet abuse of the getter/setter?

That is fine. The Swift reference [explicitly states:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262) *"You can also add property observers to any inherited property (whether stored or computed) by overriding the property within a subclass."*

> If initWithCoder is a failable initializer do I need to check if self is nil before calling adjustButtonColor()?

You don't need to (and you can't). If

```
 super.init(coder: aDecoder)
```

fails then your `init?(coder:)` method fails immediately, and the next statement
is not reached.

Comment: Thanks Martin, great explanation.  Quick follow-up: why is the type required on the second lazy var?  If I try to just declare it like `lazy var buttonSelectedColor = self.buttonColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)` I get the error "Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> RoundedButton' has no member 'buttonColor'"  Is it because of the lazy computation?

Comment: @JAL: It seems that otherwise the compiler is not smart enough to figure out that for a *lazy property*, `self` on the RHS is evaluated later and refers to the instance. For a non-lazy property `let foo = self`, the `self` on the RHS is some curried function of the type `MyButton -> () -> MyButton`.

Comment: Care to comment on La citrouille's claim below?  "I can't comment, I don't have enough gateau-juice for it, but that's obvious that a lazy instantiation on a de-referenced initializer would fail ; this is not about the compiler being smart or not."

Comment: One other question: it looks like lazy vars can't have observers.  How would I call `updateButton` like in the Objective-C `setButtonColor:` setter?

Comment: I guess I could just keep everything as `var` and just override `didSet` to call that update method.

Comment: @JAL: Yes, if you don't need that buttonSelectedColor is computed from buttonColor then you can make both ordinary stored properties with observers.

Answer (score 3):

This is a small point and not really relevant since you should absolutely go with Martin's suggestion. But **if** you stuck with your old way of doing the properties, you should rewrite your getters to use a guard instead of an if:

```
get {
    guard let color = _buttonColor else { return UIColor.grayColor() }
    return color
}
```

The reason guards are preferred over ifs in this case is that guards are more limited in their use, since there is only ever an else statement and you must exit the current function from that statement. Furthermore, guard let carries the exact semantics you need, unwrap an optional, do something with it after, do something else if it fails.